# как отменить закрытие fancybox в момент работы функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

сам код функции

```
function func() {
    //проверяем инпуты
    if (input.checkValidity() & inputnames.checkValidity()) {
        startButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)) + 1;
        if ((x % 33) == 0) {
            // 3 % вероятности
            deg = 300;
        } else if ((x % 14) == 0) {
            // 7% вероятности
            deg = 70;
        } else if ((x % 3) == 0) {
            // 30% вероятности
            deg = 240;
        } else {

            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4)) + 1;
            // 15 %
            if (x = 1) {
                //15%
                deg = 150;
            } else if (x = 2) {

                deg = 120;
            } else if (x = 3) {

                deg = 30;

  

      } else if (x = 4) {

                deg = 340;
            }
        }

        wheel.style.transition = 'all 8s ease-out';
        wheel.style.transform = `rotate(${deg + 1080}deg)`;
        // wheel.classList.add('blur');


        startButton.removeEventListener('click', func);
    }

}
```

вызов модального

```
setTimeout(function() {

        $.fancybox.open({
            src: "#popup-callbac",
            hash: "popup-callbac",
            'touch' : false,
            afterClose: function afterClose() {
                $("#popup-calc-result .popup__in .main-calc-list").remove();
    
            }
        });
        if (getCookie("played")) {
    
    
            $.fancybox.close();
        }
    }, 4000);
```

и кнопка `<button class="popup__close" id="closepops" data-fancybox-close><span></span></button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
clickSlide : 'false',
        clickOutside : 'false',
```

запрещает закрытие вне зоны модального окна